# How to fix this dropdown menu?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I need help to remove the `data-toggle` and after that show the dropdown, and when I click out of the dropdown, dropdown closes.

https://jsfiddle.net/f0yzyryL/
when changing the page I want the dropdown remains open

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
  <img src="../images/icons/icon_horario.png" class="glyph">
    <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time glyph" aria-hidden="true"></span>-->
  <span class="glyphicon-class">
    <?php echo __('horario_atendimento'); ?>                            
  </span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> <?php echo ($lang_id == 'en') ? 'pull-right' : ''; ?>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#HRsup">Suporte</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#HRuni">Unidades</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="HRuni" class="tab-pane fade">
  <p>here is the first tab</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the dropdown show on load is trivial, you just add the class `open` to the containing `li`. What you really need is a way to persist some data to tell you *when to open the menu*

The below might be the simplest:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
<li class="<?php echo ($someVar == 'someVal') ? 'open' : ''; ?>">
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/f0yzyryL/2/

You could also do this by reading and writing cookies, using localstorage, reading url parameters, using location hash..... etc :)